# Connecting Apps with Windows Azure Connect - Problem connecting

Tags: azure, azure-connect

I'm following the `Connecting Apps with Windows Azure Connect` lab in the Azure Training Kit.

- I've followed the instructions to set up the Groups and Roles, and the Activated EndPoints.
- I've updated the SQL Express settings and restarted the service
- I've installed the local endpoint, which gives the following text.
- I've added a new Windows Firewall rule

> This endpoint is configured to
>   connect, and can connect to other
>   resources in Windows Azure Connect.

I still get this error displayed in the browser.

> Sorry, an error occurred while
>   processing your request.
>
> Message: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open.  Inner Message: A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - No such host is known.)

Any ideas on why this might be or suggestions on finding out where it is failing?

Thanks.

**Update**

I found this link ["Windows Azure Connect and Symantec Endpoint Protection"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/0dde5d1a-8625-4e8a-b062-c77e00783fa9) describing a similar problem; as the title suggests Symantec EndPoint Protection could be the problem.

*Although in this case, removing Symantec did **not** fix the problem*

**Update 2**
some messages from Event Viewer - this set is repeated every 2 mins, they dont appear connected to a web page request.

at 9:29:40 [Information]

> The user SYSTEM has successfully
>   established a link to the Remote
>   Access Server using the following
>   device:  Server address/Phone Number =
>   sydrelay4.windows.azure-test.net

also at 9:29:40  [Information]

> The link to the Remote Access Server
>   has been established by user SYSTEM.

at 9:29:41 [Error]

> The user SYSTEM dialed a connection
>   named Windows Azure Connect Relay2 1
>   which has failed. The error code
>   returned on failure is 798.

at 9:29:45 [Information]

> The user SYSTEM dialed a connection
>   named Windows Azure Connect Relay2 1
>   which has terminated. The reason code
>   returned on termination is 631

Comment: I am seeing below generic connection problem when connectinig to local sql. I can ping the local box from azure instance rdp. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a conne
ction to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that
 the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed bec
ause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or est
ablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respon

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, Symantec et al. I was able to resolve it by adding the .cer certs I used in the Azure portal for the Hosted Services -> Management Certificates to my personal certificates collection via MMC and then rebooting my computer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re receiving a message like that, it’s possible that your current location has an outgoing port blocked.

Check this thread:

[SQL Azure : Connection to SQL Azure throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066347/sql-azure-connection-to-sql-azure-throws-exception)

Comment: this isnt _`sql azure`_ its _`azure connect`_. ie I'm connecting an azure web role with a local instance of sqlexpress. I dont believe the sql azure firewall rules are relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine behind a proxy? If so try to run the following commands to set proxy for the local system account:

bitsadmin /UTIL /SETIEPROXY LOCALSYSTEM NO_PROXY
bitsadmin /UTIL /SETIEPROXY LOCALSYSTEM MANUAL_PROXY a.b.c.d:80 NULL